# NStableView Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I populated my `NStableView` with tableView Controller and it's working fine. I only want to know why every time I am getting the data (Presented in table Cell) whenever the user hovers on a particular cell in a tableview, it starts displaying the data in console.

I found that this `- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` calls every time and I stack traced using instruments and this method is taking a lot of memory.

Is there any way to stop this method drawing the data every time.

Comment: just maintain a flag which observe when your table view is refreshed manually

Comment: How can i check programmatically whether user is hovering over NSTableView? Whenever i take the curosr over tableView dataCellForTableColumn is called every time.

Comment: have u get the things working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the delegate -viewWillMoveToWindow to the view subclass contain the table. here i have used the `BOOL` named `reloadTable`. [NSTrackingArea](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/MouseTrackingEvents/MouseTrackingEvents.html) is the answer for your problem

```
- (void) viewWillMoveToWindow:(NSWindow *)newWindow
{
    // Setup a new tracking area when the view is added to the window.
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[yourTable frame]
                options: (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |  
                NSTrackingActiveAlways|NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];

}

- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    reloadTable=YES;
    NSLog(@"enter %@",theEvent);

}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent*)theEvent {

     reloadTable=YES;

}
```

then use it in your `NSTableViewDataSource` methods

Comment: I am getting an error in  [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea]; should i use [tableView addTrackingArea:trackingArea]; ?

Comment: viewWillMoveToWindow is not calling, i have used NSViewController to display the views.

Comment: sorry bro the viewWillMoveToWindow is an NSView method all the above method has to be implemented in NSView subclass

Comment: Is it a wrong approach to add a NSViewController in NSWindow
- (void)setController:(NSViewController *)controller
{
    [[currentController view] removeFromSuperview];
        
    NSView *view = [controller view];

   view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;

    [_window setContentView:view];

    //[_window.contentView addSubview:view];
}

Comment: No it is not. U can use NSWindowController or NSViewController ,either way u can achieve navigating between views

Comment: Can you please share some references as i am not getting how i navigate between views in cocoa, i created NSViewControllers but for navigation from one view to another i am using the above mentioned code. I want something like in iOS development (Navigation Controller type feature for COCOA)